# Screen glitches / artifacts / flickering on all modern distros and kernels. I haven't been able to find solution for over half a year

Tags: linux-kernel, hardware, intel, intel-graphics, optimus

Description of the issue:
Horizontal lines, glitches, black or white horizontal bars appear randomly on the screen. It's very, very random. Sometimes it's barely noticeable, sometimes it's like on two videos below.
The issue has been there for almost a year. I think it started appearing arount 5.15-5.19 kernel.
Glitches don't appear in bios, refind menu, grub or Windows. Everything is perfect there.
There also seems to be no problems with nvidia graphics on linux and external displays.

Videos:
Pop os on generic kernel:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0SSLWwTSKk

Pop os on Xanmod edge:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BD8Uz7lmtaY

Fedora 39 KDE live:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyZj4bB6mq8

I've also tested on Kubuntu, Mint and MX (don't have videos but I haven't been able to find any distro that doesn't have this glitch).

Laptop specs:

- i7 8750h
- 16GB 2666MHz
- GTX 1050ti mobile (usually disabled in linux, internal display is connected to intel graphics)
- 144Hz 1080p internal display
- TongFang GK5CN5Z (sold by XMG, OverPowered, Mechrevo, PCSpecialist, Illegear, BTO, HyperBook, Eluktronics, CyberPowerPC under various names)

What I've tried so far:

- multiple distros, live and local, reinstalling them
- setting various kernel parameters related to intel graphics. max cstate seems to mitigate the problem a bit, just a little while other parameters don't do anything noticeable
- installing different kernels and versions, generic, lowlatency, xanmod, liquorix from 6.0 to 6.7.2 (tested about 40 kernels)
- checking for hardware damage, replugging internal display cable, it all seems perfect and works on Windows
- changing refresh rate
- tweaking shitton parameters in linux, I don't remember most of them, I've made at least 100-200 various changes
- memtest, no issues
- Kernel parameters: intel_idle.max_cstate=1 i915.modeset=1 i915.enable_ips=0 i915.enable_psr=0 i915.enable_dc=0 intel_iommu=igfx_off i915.enable_fbc=0 ahci.mobile_lpm_policy=1

Comment: Your Laptop is [Optimus Based: Overview](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/technologies/optimus/technology/). [Optimus: Wikipeedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus).  Did you know this?  Have you [chosen a method](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_Optimus) to drive the Optimus Framework.  Note that the Methods are universal, but the implementation of them depends on the package manager.  Therefore, choose a distribution and a driver method, and we can help  with the installation

Comment: The issue persists even if only integrated graphics is used. Nvidia graphics can't be used to drive main internal display directly and because of that, nvidia is usually disabled (in a way that if I connect external display it won't even be detected). I just turn it off to avoid issues. Sometimes I'm using pop os graphics switcher to swap to nvidia graphics but only when I need to use external display in linux.

Comment: The Optimus Framework doesn't know that, if you haven't installed it.  This is hard to explain in a comment but the NVIDIA card is discrete which means that all the Graphics Instructions are passed to the card for processing.  After the processing completes the results are passed back to the intel card for display only.  It's this "passing" back and forth that's causing the issue.  The output port is the only thing you've disabled. Click on the ArchWiki in my first comment and read "Use Integrated Graphics Only. " If your problem still exists after that let me know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's already done by https://support.system76.com/articles/graphics-switch-pop/ and
https://github.com/pop-os/system76-power Also, as I've said before, nvidia card is literally turned off and doesn't even use any power. Display is wired directly to integrated graphics.

Comment: Have you disabled the NVIDIA card in the System BIOS/Setup Firmware as recommended in the section I recommended you read?  I'm not discounting the work you described above but we both need to start from the same page.  Please read the WikI I recommended.

Comment: My bios doesn't allow disabling it. I'm sure it's disabled in kernel since if it would be active, power usage and thus battery life and temperature would be noticeable higher. Also, I don't use nouveau but proprietary driver.

Comment: Did you read "If your BIOS does not allow to disable Nvidia graphics, you can disable it from the Linux kernel itself. See Hybrid graphics#Fully power down discrete GPU.
To make sure?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uw1yVHkJ
This is my lspci. This should be enough to determine nvidia isn't even on.

Comment: Perfect, now that we both know we're on the same page, we can take a few different approaches.  We can troubleshoot the `UHD Graphics 630` and if that doesn't work, we can use the link from earlier and choose Use NVIDIA only, or Use both until we find the situation that produces the desired outcome

Comment: It's not possible to use NVIDIA only, since the internal display is connected ONLY to the integrated graphics. Even if I set it to use only Nvidia, the graphics will be rendered by Nvidia but passed to intel for displaying it on the screen. This laptop doesn't have hardware switch to switch between graphics adapters in hardware and I'm sure of it.

Comment: These are my kernel parameters that I've tried and don't fix the issue: root=UUID=8c5ece0b-cd67-439c-8107-7a38e0ce19d2 ro loglevel=0 systemd.show_status=false intel_idle.max_cstate=2 i915.modeset=1 i915.enable_ips=0 i915.enable_psr=0 i915.enable_dc=0 intel_iommu=igfx_off i915.enable_fbc=0 ahci.mobile_lpm_policy=1 splash

Comment: Are you using Plain XOrg or wayland?

Comment: I've tried them both, it makes no difference. Please notice that the glitches start before desktop environment is even loaded, in cli mode, as shown in the video.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151258/discussion-between-eyoung100-and-mariopl98).

Comment: Closing this in favor of https://askubuntu.com/q/1502229/619216